# Get Azure function app SLOT default host key using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions, terraform-provider-azure

The function app default function key can be obtained using the [function_app_host_keys](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/function_app_host_keys) data source. However I am using deployment slots for testing, and the keys are different, so I need them for the slots too. I have tried:

```
data "function_app_host_keys" "slot_default_key" {
  name = "${azurerm_windows_function_app.function.name}/slotname"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_windows_function_app.function.resource_group_name
}
```

and

```
data "function_app_host_keys" "slot_default_key" {
  name = "${azurerm_windows_function_app.function.name}-slotname"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_windows_function_app.function.resource_group_name
}
```

That is appending the slot name separated with either `/` (as it sometimes appears in the portal) or `-` (as it appears in the URL), but neither works.

Checking the azure cli, that has an additional option for slot, but the terraform documentation does not list any. Is there a way to get the slot default key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the debug output of `az functionapp keys list` with and without the `-s` (for slot) option, and the requests to management.azure.com differ in `/slots/slotname`. So I tried

```
data "function_app_host_keys" "slot_default_key" {
  name = "${azurerm_windows_function_app.function.name}/slots/${azurerm_windows_function_app_slot.slot.name}"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_windows_function_app.function.resource_group_name
}
```

and that works.

Replace with other `azurerm_*_function_app` as appropriate for your usecase—or just use names/parameters if you are not creating the function and slot yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thx Jan! just a slight modification...
use "slots" instead of "slot"

```
data "function_app_host_keys" "slot_default_key" {
name = "${...}/slots/${...}"
...
}
```